# Long Running Admin Page Requests Blocking Other Requests

Tags: adminhtml, magento-1, session, administration

If I'm logged into Magento's backend and perform some task that takes a long time (global search on large catalogs, long running dataflow, etc), my web browser will refuse to load other admin pages **in that browser only**.  Why does this happen, and is there any known science for workarounds?

That is, if I

1. Log into Magento's dashboard page
2. Open a second tab with any Magento admin page
3. Perform a long running global search (simulated with a call to `sleep(30)` at the start of `globalSearchAction`) in the first tab
4. Attempt to reload the second tab

Expected Behavior: Second tab loads with page contents immediately

Actual Behavior: Second tab only loads once the long running global search completes

Does anyone know, specifically, why this happens?  (My guess is Magento admin console requests lock some resource Magento needs to bootstrap, but I don't know what that is)

Does anyone know of a fix/workaround?

Comment: You, sir, have just sent me on a challenge! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is caused by a lock placed by the PHP session handler. So it's not Magento explicitly locking something and trying to block admin requests, but almost a side-effect per-se of file-based session storage.

A write lock is being placed on the session data file when it is opened by the initial (long-running) request, causing the second request to block until the lock is released when it calls `session_start` in `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start`

This is 100% reproducible. I used the same method you did, adding a `sleep(30)` to the top of `Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController::globalSearchAction`

Worth noting is that this cannot be reproduced if you are using db session storage. After I found the root cause, I set a sandbox to db session storage and could no longer reproduce the issue. So the db session handlers Magento has seemingly do not use row-level locking to lock session writes. I find this interesting, because it has the potential for session data loss since the application is obviously not accounting for multiple threads writing to the same session. *Note for Readers: I would never use db session storage in production to try and solve this, it's only good for overloading your MySql database.*

I didn't try reproducing the behavior using memory based session storage systems such as Redis, but my guess is that locking the records in the session store was probably overlooked in these as well.

There are techniques which could be employed to avoid this like using `session_write_close` to release the lock before you start on a long-running job. But this would also prevent you from writing to the session since you've just closed it. So it's not likely to be readily implemented across the board in Magento, but could potentially be implemented on specific routes/controllers.

My technique for pinning this as the root cause was to enable the Xdebug profiler and exam the "cachegrind" file. Once the second request completed, I loaded the output file (~25 MB log) into [MacCallGrind](http://www.maccallgrind.com) and drilled down into the trace following the path of calls where the inclusive time was 28 seconds or greater. This ultimately led me to the `session_start` call which took ~28 seconds to run, giving me a great point to research from.

**EDIT:** For the interested, I've [posted a screenshot](https://twitter.com/blackbooker/status/334661930134405121/photo/1) of the "cachegrind" file viewed in MacCallGrind on Twitter.

Comment: Unirgy's uRapidFlow module closes the session in order to avoid this issue, which is nice in a way, but it's frustrating in as much as it makes it difficult to provide feedback to the user afterwards.

Comment: @davidalger — What session storage do you typically deploy with for client sites?

Comment: Re: locking the PHP session file, this is less for for data integrity than it is for the integrity of the file-on-disk itself.  Having multiple processes opening and writing to bits on disk (which is what a file is) will quickly lead to corruption of the data. MySQL, redis, and most databases are designed specifically to stay consistent, even if there's multiple writes at nearly the same time. i.e. it's not that locking was overlooked, it's that it's not as critically needed.

Comment: @AlanStorm — A dedicated Memcached instance for a load-balanced installation, file-system for single application node clusters. File-system performs best where you don't have multiple nodes since you have no IP latency.

Comment: Correct, locking the file is all about preventing corruption of data. However, holding the lock till the session is closed is about preventing data loss. If two processes load the session data, modify it and then write it out, one of them is going to have it's modifications overwritten. Not generally going to pose a critical problem, but could cause data loss and/or nasty difficult to debug problems.

Comment: @davidalger That's an interesting way of looking at it.  I always assumed holding the lock was a performance thing. A single file operation vs. multiple file operations per PHP request.  Thanks for the perspective.

Comment: @davidalger how about to use second instance of the mysql to keep session data? Or is that possible? The reason is that to eliminate base instance from overloading.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir — I do not believe Magento supports using an isolated instance of MySql for sessions out of the box, but I've never tried it. It may via defining a session handler similar to the URLs used when configuring Memcached session storage. If you have more than a single-app-node cluster though, you'll be much better served by using a dedicated Memcached instance, as the sessions will be stored in-memory. On a single-app-node cluster (and assuming proper disk controllers/drives) you'll get the best performance with file-system sessions.