# How to get a value from a running action?

Tags: session, registry

I have a case looks like this:
Here is my controller code:

```
//example controller:

public function runAction() {
    // a example code that run a long time
    $count = 0;
    while (true) {
        $count = $count + 1;
        Mage::register('testcount', $count);
        sleep(3);
    }

}

public function viewAction() {
    echo Mage::registry("testcount");
}
```

I want to view $count while "runAction" is running by using viewAction. But the viewAction loads forever. Any solution for me?

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setTestCount($count)` and `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getTestCount()` did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the cache storage for this:

Set cache value:

```
Mage::app()->saveCache($count, 'my_counter', array(), 86400);
```

Read the cache:

```
Mage::app()->loadCache('my_counter')
```

Clear cache:

```
Mage::app()->removeCache('my_counter')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your code.
First of all `runAction` will (try) run forever because of `while(true)`, and second of all you will get an error because of this: `Mage::register('testcount', $count);`. The first time it works, the second time will give you an error because there is already a value in the registry for `testcount`.
On an other view, `Mage::register()` and `Mage::registry()` do not keep values between requests. This is just a way to set and get values 'globaly' in the same request. For passing values between requests use the session.  Or write the value in a file.

Answer (score 2):

`Mage::registry("testcount")` will expire when your current request ends. Use the session to persist values.

In addition to Marius' catch of the `while` loop never ending - the reason your controller `viewAction` never returns is most likely due to filesystem session locks. If you have a long-running request it turns out that while your filesystem session file is locked, other processes cannot access it. Try switching your session type to DB or to Memcached/APC.

See below for more information about this phenomenon:

[Long Running Admin Page Requests Blocking Other Requests](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/long-running-admin-page-requests-blocking-other-requests)